# Populate data list from Json (mobile project)

Tags: jquery, html, json, jquery-mobile

I am new in programming, and I am having a hard time tying to populate a list using Json and jQuery and PHP delivering data from MySQL. I have created a list in my HTML project:

```
<ul data-role="listview"
                style="width:60%; 
                       margin:0 auto; 
                       margin-top: 20px;
                       max-width: 250px;
                       -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
                       -moz-border-radius: 10px;
                       -border-radius: 10px ">     <!-- style not loading in css, applied directly-->                    
                    <li><a href="#module1">Dynamic Web Development</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#module2">Human Computing Interaction</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#module3">Introduction to Programming</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#module4">Design Principles</a></li>  
                    <li><a href="#module5">Design Practice</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#module6">Digital Audio</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#module7">Digital Signal Processing</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#module8">History of Digital Media</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#module9">Digital Asset Management</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#module10">Production Skills</a></li>
                 </ul> <!-- end modules list-->
```

When you click on each item from the list, its linked to another page e.g module 1:

```
<div id="module1"
             data-role="page">
        <div data-role="header"
             data-position='fixed'>
            <h1>Module 1</h1>
             <a href="#modules"
              data-icon="back">Modules</a>
        </div> <!--header-->    
        <div data-role="content">
            <h2 style="text-align:center;">Module specifications</h2>
            <ul data-role="listview"
                style="width: 60%; margin: 0 auto">
                <li>Module Name:</li>
                <li>Credits:</li>
                <li>Module no.:</li>
                <li>Location:</li>
                <li>Website:</li>
            </ul>
```

As you can see, I have a list there that I want to populate with JSON format from PHP.
From my console:

```
0: Object
credits: "15"
dueDate: "2013-05-14"
lat: "53.338545"
location: "Aungier Street"
long: "-6.26607"
moduleName: "Dynamic Web Development"
moduleNo: "999001"
room: "4037"
website: "www.dynWeb.ie"
```

How can I target those fields in my list using jQuery??

Comment: http://www.gajotres.net/advanced-jquery-mobile-tutorial-part-2-client-server-communication/

Answer (score 0):

You can give the listitems a unique class or ID and then easily target them in script. For example. add class names in the markup:

Module Name:
        Credits:
        Module no.:
        Location:
        Website:

Then in script:

```
   obj = {
        credits: "15",
        dueDate: "2013-05-14",
        lat: "53.338545",
        location: "Aungier Street",
        long: "-6.26607",
        moduleName: "Dynamic Web Development",
        moduleNo: "999001",
        room: "4037",
        website: "www.dynWeb.ie"
    };

    $(".liModuleName").html("Module Name: " + obj.moduleName);
    $(".liCredits").html("Credits: " + obj.credits);
    $(".liModuleNo").html("Module no.: " + obj.moduleNo);
    $(".liLocation").html("Location: " + obj.location);
    $(".liWebsite").html("Website: " + obj.website);
```

> Here is a **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/BX57J/)**

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the answer. The issue is that the obj comes form PHP file. So, what is mentioned as a objet, is the result in my web browser console. :)

Comment: i understood your question was asking how to target the listitems in your page. If the question is how to get JSON data via PHP/AJAX, perhaps you can reword the question...